# How to display the most popular posts of all the blogs in a mu setup?

Tags: multisite

When you visit wordpress.com, they have a list of the most popular posts right on the front page. I was wondering if there was a way to do the same thing on my multisite installation. Is it possible, and if it is, how would I go about doing it (plugin? theme?)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WP Multisite Popular Posts plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multisite-popular-posts/) in order to show most commented posts across the network. This plugin allows you to use a shortcode or a widget in order to display the most commented posts accross the network. You can also choose the number of posts to display in the list and the concerned time period.

Comment: An answer should be more than just a link to an external site. Please add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?